# Why can't I embed implicit calls

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Say I have the following:

```
class A {
    def foo() = { println("foo") }
}

case class B(a: A)

implicit def toA(b: B) = b.a

implicit def wrapper(a: A) = new {
    def bar() = a.foo()
}
```

Then I cannot do the following:

```
val b = B(new A())
b.bar() // cannot resolve
```

Rather I need to explicitly call the toA() implicit:

```
toA(b).bar()
```

or do

```
(b: A).bar()
```

Why is it that the compiler does not know to apply the first implicit before applying the second implicit, wrapper?

Comment: That would require two implicit resolutions. I guess the compiler just gives up after one implicit resolution - if it would try harder, compilation could take extremely longer times. Also, IMHO, depend on two implicits makes the code very hard to reason, also implicit conversions themselves are considered a bad practice. Why do not simply  add an extension method `foo` directly to `B`?

Comment: Unfortunately the scenario I have would not allow modifications to B - this was as simple as I could make the example.

Comment: I mean `implicit class BOps (val b: B) extends AnyVal { def foo(): = b.a.bar() }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **One-at-a-time Rule: Only one implicit is tried.** The compiler will never rewrite `x + y` to `convert1(convert2(x)) + y`. Doing so would cause compile times to increase dramatically on erroneous code, and it would increase the difference between what the programmer writes and what the program actually does. For sanity's sake, the compiler does not insert further implicit conversions when it is already in the middle of trying another implicit. However, it's possible to circumvent this restriction by having implicits take implicit parameters, which will be described later in this chapter.

Section [21.2 Rules for implicits](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html#21.2), from Programming in Scala, [First Edition](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/)
by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, and Bill Venners.